# Switching between scenes blocks unity camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality

If i run a scene normally in unity 3D it looks nice, but if i switch to it from another scene the camera became blocked and crashed without giving me any error!! Am i missing something?  I am working with unity pro 4.5.0 and  Nyartoolkit .

Here are 2 screenshot of my two scenes:
[image]

[image]

the first screenshot is my second scene and the second one is the hierarchy of my first scene !!??

It's the same problem when switching from the first scene to the second scene or going back from the second scene to my first one. In all cases the camera became black as it is clear in first screenshot .

Comment: Do both scenes contain cameras?

Comment: @ ElDuderino yes both contain cameras. btw is it a problem that both scenes contain the same name of gameObject !! Because i have an iGUI root for both .

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem @Narkinchi 
Please post something for us to look at, maybe a screenshot of your hierarchy?

Comment: Two questions I could think of that may help us understand what is going on: (1)When you load the next scene, are you using `Application.LoadLevel` or `Application.LoadLevelAdditive`? (2)Is there an object with a script calling `GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)`? If yes, could it be that when you load the second scene, this object is staying right in front of the camera?

Comment: @GabrielCoutinho , no, for your first question am using Application.LoadLevel     to swich between scenes and  i don't have any game object with script calling  'GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)'   but i have four gameObjects that are generated by script at run time in the second scene . Could that be a problem!?

Comment: I don't think the objects generated by script are a problem. If they were a problem, you would still have this bug when running the scene from the editor, and not only when the scene is loaded after another scene

Comment: yes, i thought so too...but, after this problem am doubting in everything because i coud'nt figure out where exactly could be the problem.